# Matlab equals not working

Tags: matlab, equals

Really simple question... I'm trying to exit a while loop early:

```
while optimal < 1 
    %some code...
    x=0  %This is just here to set my example...
    if x~=0
      break
    end 
end
```

But for some reason even though x was set to 0, the if statement always fails as it says x isnt equal to 0 and the while loops will never exit

Thanks!

Comment: I think you must use `x==0` rather than `x~=0`

Comment: Are you **absolutely** sure that `x = 0`?  Are you doing some calculations in your loop where `x` is **expected to be** zero when it isn't?  This post may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab

Answer (score 2):

if you want to exit if x i equal to 0 then you want to write:

```
if x==0
```

however, unless you want to exit the loop before the end, you could also add the condition on the x in the while line:

```
while (optimal < 1 && x~=0)
```

"as long as optimal is less than one and x is NOT 0"